# Calculate the limit

Tags: calculus, limits

To calculate the limit $\lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 1)} x^2y$ do we have to do the following ??

If $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 1)$ we have that $x \rightarrow 0$ and $y \rightarrow 1$ so $x^2y \rightarrow 0$.

Or should we say that the function $x^2y$ is continuous as the product of two continuous functions, so the limit of the function is the product of the limit of the functions $x^2$ and $y$ ??

Or do we have to say something else??

Comment: The function $x^2y$ is continuous, so the limit is equal to the value at $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x,y)=x^2y$ is continuous for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we can simply evaluate $$ \lim_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 1)} x^2y=(0)^2(1)=0.$$

Comment: In other words, "we say that the function $x^2y$ is continuous as the product of two continuous functions."